# Drools HelloWorld Example Fresh Install Throws Null Pointer

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

Console Output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:23)
```

Lines 12-28 in the DroolsTest.Java

```
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

        // go !
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage("Hello World");
        message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
        kSession.insert(message); //This is 23
        kSession.fireAllRules();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Windows 7. Fresh Install of Eclipse, Java, and the Drools Plugin.

I've seen other people receiving the null pointer error, but it's when the Drools Core isn't present and they get about 15 more errors with it. I can't find anyone receiving just these 2.

I'm assuming I missed some install piece, but I can't figure it out. Additionally, I have the slf4j-api.jar file in the Drools Library visible in the package Explorer.

I'm pretty new to Java, so shoot me questions and I'll post snippets you need to see.

I can Navigate in the Package Explorer to the "org.kie.api.runtime.rule.EntryPoint.insert(Object arg0)" place it's calling, but I see a page that says "Class File Editor" then "Source Not Found"

Comment: "Fresh Install" - It dosen't matter. Code you download almost always needs a little tweaking. Look into kContainer... obviously it's returning a null at line 16, so investigate why.

Comment: @Martin Here's what I'm seeing. I take it I'm missing some file? Thanks for your help. http://i.imgur.com/dTL9EX5.jpg

Comment: 1. I don't think you are missing a file. The reason you cannot see the source is because JARs are not ment to be read. 2. I can't help you much since I don't know what 'drools' is. 3. Keep searching the web until you get an answer here. In your place I would start by looking for `drools: newKieSession return null` or something similar. 4. Of course print it to the screen and make sure it's a null, and don't trust me too much :)

Comment: Please post a link to where you got hold of that sample project.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that one needs to supply three values. One can either use the three text boxes on the "Drools Runtime" panel that the wizard puts up, or one can manually update the pom.properties file in the project. The three values that have been working for me are:

```
groupId=com.test.sample.drools
artifactId=DroolsTestProject
version=1
```

In my case the pom.properties file is in C:\Users\clark\workspace\HelloWorld\src\main\resources\META-INF\maven where "HellowWorld" is the name I gave to the project.

The basic answer, that I have elaborated on above, can be found here: [Getting null pointer exception while running helloworld in drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315910/getting-null-pointer-exception-while-running-helloworld-in-drools)

[The code shown in the original question is generated by the Drools project wizard. File ... New ... Project ... Drools Project ... then check the top two checkboxes on "New Drools Project"]

Answer (score 0):

Those projects use Maven for their configuration. You need to either:

1. Run "mvn eclipse:eclipse" from the command line whilst in the root of the project.
2. Install the m2e Eclipse plugin so that your Eclipse IDE can recognise Maven project structures and load the appropriate dependencies.