# Getting NullPointerException while reading rules file

Tags: java, web-services, maven, drools

I am trying to create a Axis2 archive which I am deploying on axis2 framework. It's a simple hello world service which accepts a parameter name. Now in this web service, I have tried out an example to integrate with drools. I have done all the necessary steps to execute drools example as webservice, here is my archive structure:

[image]

**Now in the resource folder i have rules folder inside that i have .drl file**
**In the META-INF Folder i have kmodule.xml and pom.properties**
**and inside com folder i have .class files**

Now when I run this web service through SoapUI, I get an error saying:

Null pointer exception at below line :-

```
kSession.insert(message);
```

Here is the complete code:-

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

// go !
Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("Hello World");
message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
kSession.insert(message);
kSession.fireAllRules();
```

As per my knowledge, here it is not able to find the rules file or the .drl file. Now the question is where should I place the .drl file so that at the above line of code finds the .drl file.

Really looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `kSession` is `null`

Comment: how you are initializing `ksession`? can you post the code.

Comment: Can you supply the complete stack trace that you're getting?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315910/getting-null-pointer-exception-while-running-helloworld-in-drools

Comment: it seems like the folder structure of my project is wrong. Can some one point out what it should be